# VB.Net - System.InvalidOperationException: 'Invoke or BeginInvoke cannot be called on a control until the window handle has been created.'

Tags: vb.net

I have one VB.net windows application project.  When I try to debug it I get following error.

Surprisingly, same project works on other two PCs, but does not work on one particular PC.

Following is the code under frmMain.Designer.vb

```
Imports System.IO
<Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.DesignerGenerated()>
Partial Class frmMain
        Inherits DevExpress.XtraBars.Ribbon.RibbonForm
     Protected Overrides Sub SetVisibleCore(ByVal value As Boolean)
        Try
            If Not Me.IsHandleCreated Then
                Me.CreateHandle()
                value = False
            End If
            MyBase.SetVisibleCore(value)
        Catch ex As Exception
            Mycon.InformationMessage(ex.ToString)
        End Try
      End Sub
```

The error I get:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'Invoke or BeginInvoke cannot be called on a control until the window handle has been created.'

This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    System.Windows.Forms.Control.MarshaledInvoke(System.Windows.Forms.Control, System.Delegate, object[], bool)
    System.Windows.Forms.Control.Invoke(System.Delegate, object[])
    wyDay.Controls.AutomaticUpdater.auBackend_CheckingFailed(object, wyDay.Controls.FailArgs)
    wyDay.Controls.AutomaticUpdaterBackend.UpdateStepFailed(wyDay.Controls.UpdateStepOn, wyDay.Controls.FailArgs)
    wyDay.Controls.AutomaticUpdaterBackend.updateHelper_PipeServerDisconnected(object, wyUpdate.Common.UpdateHelperData)
    wyDay.Controls.UpdateHelper.bw_RunWorkerCompleted(object, System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs)
    System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.OnRunWorkerCompleted(System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) in BackgroundWorker.cs
    System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.AsyncOperationCompleted(object) in BackgroundWorker.cs
    System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context(object) in threadpool.cs
    System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, object, bool) in executioncontext.cs
    ...
    [Call Stack Truncated]
```

I extensively searched and found few common suggestions.

One I tried was: check or uncheck "Enable Just My Code", some says uncheck and some says do opposite to existing state (If checked, then Uncheck, and if unchecked then do Check)

This option does not resolve my issue always. I am trying above method 15-20 times, and out of 15-25 tries, it works once.
Then if I stop debugging and tries to debug again, same issue arises, then I follow same cycle again for 30 mins, and if lucky it work once.

If I check "Enable Just My Code", I get a different error saying:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'Invoke or BeginInvoke cannot be called on a control until the window handle has been created.'
This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    [External Code]
```

If I uncheck "Enable Just My Code", it throws first error as shown above.

Somewhere I read that check "Microsoft Symbol Servers" under Tools>Options>Debugging>Symbols
This did not work at all.

I took Exported VisualStudio settings from PC where project always runs successfully and restored VS settings on PC where the project is throwing error.
But the same issue arises always.

What I observed is, when I run same project on PC where it is working well, debug goes only once inside code under frmMain.designer.vb

```
Try
        If Not Me.IsHandleCreated Then
            Me.CreateHandle()
            value = False
        End If
        MyBase.SetVisibleCore(value)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Mycon.InformationMessage(ex.ToString)
    End Try

End Sub
```

But on PC where Debugging throws an error, it goes two times inside the same code of Designer.
First time it does not throw any error but when it goes again in same code (i do not why), it throws an error and stops debugging.

I am amused that Why only Check/Unchecking "Enable Just My Code" sometimes works.
And why same project has no issue with debugging on other PCs.

Comment: Looks familiar, attribution is required here.  This is a threading race bug, it will act differently on different machines.  The BGW gets started too soon, and completes before SetVisibleCore() could run.  It is only guaranteed to be safe when you start it after the CreateHandle() call.  Also make sure that the worker is completed before you allow the form to close.  And that you actually *need* a BGW, clearly it is getting its job done very quickly.

Comment: It's an update checker? Does it need to check for an update even before the window has appeared? Would it kill anything to do the update check 5 seconds after the program finished launching? "hi user, there's an update available; do you want it now, upon exit, upon next launch or never?"

Comment: @CaiusJard, I just removed all update checker process, still issue persist.

Comment: @HansPassant,Since I took over the existing lengthy project, I am trying to figure out about BGWorker and SetVisiableCore().When Application starts, it first loads frmLogin, and after successful login, it loads frmMain where this issue arises.